# Hiding siblings if none are visible

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have the following, would be great if someone could help..

```
    $(".brand-nav").click(function(e){
        var type = $(this).attr( id );
        $('.article').hide();
        $('.' + type).show();            
        e.preventDefault();            
        $(".letter-section").each(function (i) {
            var siblings = $(i).siblings(":visible").length;
            if (siblings == 0) {
                $(i.big-lettter').hide();
            } else {
                $(i.big-lettter').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I've made this JS fiddle to include an idea of the HTML too on: http://jsfiddle.net/BEa4x/ as I when I posted it here it didn't format correctly.

When you click on the top menu it should hide all of the links and then only show the relevant ones by the ID of the link.

If then you click on food that means there will be no links visible in the 'A' section, therefore I would need the A hiding as well, else it should be shown.

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: You know that you have spelled letter with three 't'´s right?

Comment: $(i).siblings(":visible").size();

Comment: Yeah sorry forget the spelling.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there are a few syntax errors in there... and some logic errors. Try this:

```
 $(".brand-nav").click(function(e) {
     var type = $(this).attr('id'); // id needs quotes
     $('.article').hide();
     $('.' + type).show();            
     e.preventDefault();            
     $(".letter-section").each(function (i) {
         var siblings = $(this).find('li').filter(':visible'); // i is the index, "this" is the actual DOM element. Also you need the descendants 'li', not his siblings
         if (siblings.size() == 0) {
             $(this).children('.big-letter').hide(); // again, use "this" and get the children (you may want to filter the first also).
         }
         else {
             $(this).children('.big-letter').show(); // remember to show again or it will stay hidden :)
         }
     }); // you also forgot to close this bracket
 });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BEa4x/21/

Comment: That's spot on thank you - I didn't know you could use (this) as I thought that might still be from the click!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".brand-nav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();            

        // Note that id has to be quoted here.
        var kind = $(this).attr('id');

        // First of all show all the letters
        // in case they had been hidden previously
        $('.letter-section').show();

        // Hide all the articles and only show the ones that
        // match the id of the element that's been clicked on.
        $('.article').hide();
        $('.' + kind).show();

        // For each letter section...
        $('.letter-section').each(function(index, element) {
            // Check if its visible li count is 0
            if ($(element).contents('li:visible').length == 0) {
              // If it is, hide the letter!
              $(element).hide();   
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BEa4x/23/

This is a pretty quick and dirty fix-up of your code, I would refactor it if I was you, beginning with putting the letter-section contents check into its own function.